# Prove that for any n > 3 there is a set of n point sites in the plane such that one of the cells of Voronoi diagram(P) has n − 1 vertices

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm, voronoi

I am trying to solve some exercises of the book "Computational Geometry Algorithm and Applications, 3rd - de berg et al" of chapter 7 - Voronoi Diagrams. Unfortunately, I am not sure if understand the following question:

```
Prove that for any n > 3 there is a set of n point sites in the plane such that one of the cells of Voronoi diagram(P) has n − 1 vertices
```

The problem is when I look at the following figure of the book:
[image]

There are 11 site points, but I do not see **any** cell with 10(11-1) vertices. Does this mean I have to proof that this is not true? Or did I not understand the question correctly

Comment: you'll probably get more help at [Math Stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) I'd try posting there too

Comment: Your second hypothesis holds. The theorem says that you can find such a placement of the points (take a regular polygon of n-1 sides and its center), not that it works with any diagram.

Answer (score 0):

For each set, you have to find one configuration that works. If you place one point at the origin, and all the others regularly around a circle of radius 1, the cell of the origin has n-1 vertices.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw an octagon. add one more vertices in middle of that polygon
 Draw voronoi polygon bu making triangles .
At end u will have 8 edges and 8 vertices. 'hence proved